Why can't I use a row-polymorphic variable?
Take a look at this PureScript code:
type MyOtherProps = (value :: String)
type MyProps = (a :: String)

a
  :: forall props phantom allProps
   . Union MyProps MyOtherProps allProps
  => Union props phantom allProps
  => { | props }
  -> Unit
a {} = unit

b = a { a: "hello", value: "apple" }

If I attempt to pattern match on the {} with anything that is not {}, such as
a {value} = unit

Then I get an error. Why?
Background
I am trying to make providing any of the union record labels optional, so I can call a without providing a or value labels. I understand that if I use the variable in the body of a, that it would be unsound to use any of the values in the record because they might or might not exist. But I don't understand how the compiler knows this is the case. I also know it has something to do with the inference of the phantom type, which the compiler fills in. But at the end of the day, the type of allProps is well-defined, so I don't understand why this pattern match fails theoretically, I do know why in practice.
Error Output
[1/1 TypesDoNotUnify] src\Main.purs:45:3

  45  a {a} = unit
        ^^^

  Could not match type
    props0
  with type
    ( a :: t2
    | t3
    )
  while trying to match type Record props0
    with type Record t1
  while checking that expression case $1 of
                                   { a: a } -> unit
    has type Unit
  in value declaration a
  where props0 is a rigid type variable
          bound at (line 0, column 0 - line 0, column 0)
        t1 is an unknown type
        t3 is an unknown type
        t2 is an unknown type


